# How to check that two events hrappend on different days in doctrine

Tags: sql, date, datetime, doctrine

I've already recognized that I cannot use functions like `date()` in doctrine. Of course otherwise I could just use simple expression like `date(a.start) < date(b.start)` (where `a.start` and `b.start` are datetimes).

But if I have to know that two events (like `2020-01-15 23:59:59` and `2020-01-16 00:00:01`) happend in different days, is there way to check it with default doctrine tools?